# initWithData: expected struct NSData * warning

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

I am getting a strange warning with my initWithData: method:

> warning: incompatible Objective-C
>   types 'struct NSDictionary *',
>   expected 'struct NSData *' when
>   passing argument 1 of 'initWithData:'
>   from distinct Objective-C type

in TRDevice.h:

```
@interface TRDevice : NSObject
{
    NSString *name;      
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;

-(id)initWithData:(NSDictionary *)inData;

@end
```

in TRDevice.m:

```
- (id)initWithData:(NSDictionary *)inData
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        self.name = [inData valueForKey:TRDeviceNameKey];
    }
    return self;
}
```

And where I try to instantiate the above object:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *dataArray = [prefs arrayForKey:TRDevicesKey];
for (NSDictionary *data in dataArray)
{
    TRDevice *device = [[TRDevice alloc] initWithData:data];
    [self.devices addObject:device];
    [device release];
}
```

This warning goes away if I 1) rename the init method to something else such as `initWithDictionary:`. or 2) if I pass in `nil` to `initWithData:`.

AFAIK NSObject implements no initWithData: method so I am not overriding it either. I have no clue why I'm getting this warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+alloc` does not return `NSObject`, it returns `id`. that's the proper declaration. the type is (from the compiler's perspective) erased when it's returned via `+ (id)alloc`.

most uses of `initWithData:` take NSData as their first argument. this is part of the reason objc 'reads so well' and is descriptive.

anyways... personally, i'd just rename it to `initWithDictionary:` for clarity, convention, and to avoid the warning.

another option is to simply declare your initializer to include the type:

```
- (id)initTRDeviceWithData:(NSDictionary *)data;
```

this is detailed enough that it is not likely to conflict with other classes in the translation.

or you can declare a convenience constructor:

```
+ (TRDevice *)newTRDeviceWithData:(NSDictionary *)data;
```

or a variant for an autoreleased type:

```
+ (TRDevice *)trDeviceWithData:(NSDictionary *)data; // eww...
```